# Affine line bundles on affine schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is all line bundles on an affine scheme ample?

Let us take the definition of ampleness as in the ``stacks project''. 
A line bundle (i.e invertible sheaf) $\mathcal{L}$ on a quasi-compact scheme $X$ is called ample if for every $x\in X$ there is an integer $n\geq 1$ and a global section $s\in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})$  such that  $$X_s:=\{x\in X\, | \, s_x\not\in \mathcal{m}_x\cdot (\mathcal{L}^{\otimes n})_x\}$$ is affine and $x\in X_s$.

Any comments are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I feel confused. My definition of ample is that some multiple is very ample, and my definition of very ample is that the corresponding map induces an closed embedding in projective space. So this can never happens for an affine variety except points.

Comment: In the definition of very ampleness, the induced morphism is required to be  an immersion, not a closed embedding.

Comment: Yes, they are ample. A standard way is to prove first that your definition of ampleness is equivalent to the following: For any coherent sheaf $F$, for all   $n\gg 0$,  $H^1(F\otimes L^n)=0$. For affine schemes, this vanishing is true for all coherent sheaves and so you are done.